# Does "pub upgrade" upgrade incrementally or straight to latest versions?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

According to "pub --help" the "upgrade" command is used to:

> Upgrade the current package's dependencies to latest versions.

However, I just had to run "pub upgrade" several times to reach the current latest versions of packages that my pubspec.yaml depends on. It seemed like each run upgraded only incrementally. What am I missing?

Specific example I observed was mustache: ">=0.1.5", which was first upgraded to 0.1.6 and on a second run to 0.1.7.

pub version: Pub 1.1.0-dev.5.11

Answer (score 1):

It should upgrade all dependencies to the latest version available, or the latest version allowed in pubspec.yaml [(see the Pub Package Manager docs)](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/pub-upgrade.html).

But if it jumps only over one new version per upgrade, try to fill in the [bug](http://dartbug.com/new)

Comment: It's hard to reproduce as my pub cache is now contaminated. But I'll keep an eye on it.

Comment: I recommend to use latest stable version of the pub (1.1.1 I think) and I also recommend to delete the pub directory and packages directories, then run 'pub get' again in order to get all depencencies  anew. (it's called pub/dependency rebuilding).

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen that behavior. It should go straight to the highest available (not-dev) release that fulfills your dependency constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this behaviour if a new version of your dependency lands between your 2 runs.

Looking at the versions of [mustache](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mustache) (click on the *Versions* tab) you can see if a new version has landed during your test. It may explain what you observed.